# how to add a li with the before selector css

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add a `li` before the li in a list doing this:

```
ul.ssmenu:first-child::before{
    li{
        position: relative;
        height: 10px;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an element like that using CSS only, the `::before` is an element though, a pseudo element, and you could do like this..., and if you need more `li`, you'll need to use a script

```css
ul li,
ul::before,
ul::after {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
ul::before {
  content: 'This li were added with CSS pseudo ::before';
  display: list-item;
}
ul::after {
  content: 'This li were added with CSS pseudo ::after';
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This "li" exist in markup</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ul.ssmenu{
    li:first-child::before{
        position: relative;
        height: 10px;
    }
}
```